# SCP / SSHEXEC - number of connection attempts

Tags: ant, connection, scp

I am using scp task followed by sshexec in my ant build.xml. I derive the value for password from a Password field on the screen. The user doesnt have the ability to check if its the right password or not until the task completes successfully.

As a result, if the entered password is incorrect, does Scp / sshexec retry to connect? Is there any handle to limit the number of connection retries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sshexec` and `scp` tasks use Java Secure Channel [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), see ant manual [library dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies).
I had a similiar problem, as JSch tries to authenticate 6 times configured in the com.jcraft.jsch.JSch Class. When wrong password was used, the user account got locked.
Simply patched the com.jcraft.jsch.JSch Class like this :

from :

```
config.put("MaxAuthTries", "6");
```

to :

```
config.put("MaxAuthTries", "3");
```

Means JSch will only try 3 times to authenticate.

**-- Edit after comment --**

1. Download JSch release zip [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch/0.1.51/jsch-0.1.51.zip/download) - the latest version is 0.1.51
2. Unzip
3. Open jsch-0.1.51/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.java
4. Change line 124
   from
    config.put("MaxAuthTries", "6");
   to
    config.put("MaxAuthTries", "3");
5. Save
6. Run jsch-0.1.51/build.bat or build.sh according to your OS
7. Use jsch-0.1.51/dist/lib/jsch-0.1.5.jar

Comment: First appreciate your response !! .. but how do i patch the binary file.. am relatively new to this and not sure how to create the patch.

Comment: Added some instructions - see updated answer. If you don't succeed i may mail the patched jar.

Comment: Uploaded file => http://wikisend.com/download/139984/jsch-0.1.51-patched.jar The file will be available 7 days MD5 = 2893A131C6775DCA1DB999D1EBADE566

Comment: that was so amazing of you to give me such detailed instructions .. thanks a lot !!!

Comment: My pleasure - that's what stackoverflow.com is all about :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution which does not require you to manually patch and rebuild the JSch library.

In order to limit the retry count to 1, just add the following `script` snippet either at the beginning of your Ant script, or before invoking `scp` and `sshexec` tasks, e.g.:

```
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
     com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.setConfig("MaxAuthTries", "1");
]]> </script>

<sshexec host="..." username="..." password="..." command="..."/>
```

You'll need JSch 0.1.46 or higher! I tested with Ant 1.9.4 and JSch 0.1.51 / 0.1.52.

Comment: This worked perfectly for our team and to me seems like the preferred way to go as opposed to the accepted answer.  Place this `script` tag within your ant target above the `sshexec` tag and it just works, nothing else needed.